# Project array elements as individual fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with a field in each document that looks like:

```
{
   person = [{"name":"Alex"},{"name":"Betsy"},{"name":"Chauncy"}]
}
```

Documents can have different length for this array
I'm trying to project the individual element of this array as fields within the same document with the key as `Name {index}` and the corresponding value for the name. I can't seem to generate the projected fields given an array.

Expected output:

```
[{
"name1": "Alex",
"name2": "Betsy",
"name3": "Chauncy"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array and it helps to get the index too
- `$group` to reconstruct the array with key (k): value(v) pair which helps in next stage
- `$arrayToObject` since group already made k:v pair, this helps to make array to opbect
- `$replaceRoot` helps to make the object as root

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: { path: "$person", includeArrayIndex: "index" }
  },  
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      person: {
        $push: {
          k: { "$concat": [ "name", { $toString: "$index" } ] },
          v: "$person.name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      person: { "$arrayToObject": "$person" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$person" }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KEGVWgoC7eu)**

Comment: I've tried using $unwind before, but that creates a new document for each array element. I want to keep all the elements in the same document (I'm projecting a lot of other fields as the original document is pretty big). What I'm trying to do is to append each `name` key with it's index and project that as the key and it's value.

Comment: can u update the question with the expected output

Comment: i've updated the question with the expected output

Comment: @ChiragBansal I have updated my answer. Please have a look